# Selecting Data from User Input with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a form containing some CheckedListBoxes as seen here: 
[image]

I am able to drill down my data from the first two columns via:

```
var take = await cmax.dbases.Where(w => statuses.Any(a => w.statusname == a) 
                                        && portfolios.Any(a => w.portfolio == a)).Take(Math.Min((int) takeAmount, count - taken)).ToListAsync();
```

I would like to then be able to `Select()` specific data based on my selection in the 2nd two CheckedListBoxes, however, the only method I know to Select Data with EntityFramework is:

```
Select(s => new { s.ColumnNameHere, s.OtherColumnNameHere });
```

How may I select the specific properties(columns) based on the user input?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [DynamicLinq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

With it it's possible to write select statements like that (example from site above):

```
var query = db.Customers.Select("new (CompanyName as Name, Phone)");
```

So you need to create a string a list of fields and concatenated them or something else.

Comment: How do I then interact with the data?



`var take =
                        await
                            cmax.dbases.Where(
                                w => statuses.Any(a => w.statusname == a) && portfolios.Any(a => w.portfolio == a)).Select(selectQuery.ToString())
                                .Take(Math.Min((int) takeAmount, count - taken))
                                .ToListAsync();`


When attempting to interact with `take.*` I am provided only `.ToString();`

Comment: I assume you should specify full list of fields in select statement.

Comment: I do, however what is returned is a `List<object>`, and if I convert that to string I get: `"{filenumber=345400, custom2=, custom3=, custom6=4076995332, custom8=4072121417}"`. No matter what I do I cannot cast it to the original object.